# Oracle NUM_CPUS, NUM_CPU_SOCKETS and Connection Pooling

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, connection-pooling

I read about Oracle connection pooling size. Official documents say:

> For example, suppose a server has 2 CPUs and each CPU has 18 cores.
> Each CPU core has 2 threads. Based on the Oracle Real-Wold Performance
> group guidelines, the application can have between 36 and 360
> connections to the database instance.

My Oracle server's NUM_CPUS are 16, NUM_CPU_CORES are 8 but NUM_CPU_SOCKETS are 2. It means we have 2 CPU in fact but with multithreading it works like 16 CPU.

I am not sure which one to use in connection formula. Probably 16 but I'm asking here to be sure.

16cpu * 8cores = min 128 connection?

or

2cpu * 8cores = min 16 connection?

Which one applies to me. :/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `2 cpu * 8 cores = 16 minimum connections`.

This sentence in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adfns/connection_strategies.html#GUID-841C6E1B-00A3-41AA-A5A8-9740E4EBA929) implies that the rule is meant for physical CPUs and cores: "The number of connections should be based on the number of CPU cores and not the number of CPU core threads." Your NUM_CPUS value of 16 must be a "logical" CPU since the system only has 2 sockets.

Comment: But docs say for NUM_CPUS: The NUM_CPUS Oracle metric indicates the number of CPUs or processors available. So i confused. They don't say it's core thread number, they say CPU number. :/

Comment: @LacOniC I think you're referring to [this dba-oracle.com article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/m_num_cpus.htm) article. That page seems to be 20 years old, before processors had cores and every definition of CPU was a physical CPU. That site contains some questionable information so you should ignore it if possible.